# Can I do an app like Find my iphone in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, locking, tracking, locate

I want to create an app which has the following features.

- Track friends / family members location
- Locate/track the stolen device location
- Lock the device, delete the device datas by using desktop or by SMS.

Most of the above features are provided by Apple's "Find my iPhone" app. But I just want to know whether is it possible to create such an app.

From my understanding, Apple wont let the developers to use private API's and they wont allow to erase datas (like Messages, Calls details) remotely.

Please suggest me some ideas.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You cannot create an application like this on iOS. Come up with another idea.

Comment: Of course it's "possible" in the abstract, absolute sense - **Apple did it.**

Comment: The reason why I asked this question is to understand the standards of Apple and the possibility of over write an Apple's existing apps. Thanks for the comments & downgrading this question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you create any app which directly competes with any of the apples build app will be rejected by appstore.. But most of the above things you can do with private api's and with the help of a web service..

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't possible prior to iOS7. App was not able to respond to any remote calls. There is a new API which "can" be used to solve similar things: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-mutlitasking-enhancements/ or http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html (Remote notifications). You may be able to track your friends or stolen device, but not to lock or erase it.

There is a way to remotely erase the iPhone without Apple's Find My iPhone - via Exchange account. There are some open source implementations of MS Exchange, so there may be a chance to make a service which would be able to wipe the device. But even when you make that service, there will be a need to add the "exchange account" into the iDevice. I am not aware of any function which can do so programmatically.

Anyway - You can do an app which is similar to Apple's apps, but it must be somehow different. It must provide some special content or functionality, otherwise it will be rejected.